# Find the sum of all natural numbers less than and coprime to $N=25200$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

I have factorized the number $25200=2⋅2⋅2⋅2⋅3⋅3⋅5⋅5⋅7$. I found the sum of all numbers from $1$ to $25199$. I got the number $317507400$. Then, as I understand it, I have to calculate the sums of all numbers that are multiples of $2;3;5;7$ and subtract these sums from the total. But at the same time, one must probably take into account that, for example, in the number $6$ there are already $2$ and $3$, and in the number $15$ there are already numbers $3$ and $5$, and there are many such options and how to take this into account is not very clear. Or is there an easier way to solve it?

Comment: Note that a number is coprime to this number if and only if it is coprime to $210$ or alternatively has none of the prime factors $2,3,5,7$. Apply inclusion-exclusion and note that you can calculate the needed sums with the help of the sum of the numbers $1$ to $k$ multiplied by some number.

Comment: @Peter The formula of inclusions-exclusions, as I understand it: from the largest number $25199$, subtract the number of multiples of $2,3,5,7$ separately, then add the number of multiples of $6,10,14,15,21,35$, then add the number of multiples of $30,42,70,105$, and then add the number multiples of $210$. In each case, we count the sums of these numbers, we add or subtract these numbers depending on their signs. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The numbers less than $25200$ and coprime to $25200$ come in pairs of the form $k, 25200 - k$. Then: do you know how many numbers there are coprime to $25200$?

Comment: As far as I understand, since the number $25200$ itself is divisible by $2,3,5,7$, then coprime numbers less than $25200$ and coprime with $25200$ these will be prime numbers from $11$ to a prime number less than $25200$, the last prime number will be equal to $525189$. I can take them from the table of prime numbers and add them, but this is very cumbersome.

Comment: If you know the prime factorization of $n$, there is a simple formula for the number of numbers less than or equal to $n$ and coprime to $n$.  If this is not familiar to you, try looking up "Euler phi function".

Comment: Using the Euler function, I determined the number of numbers not exceeding $25200$ and coprime with $25200$, I got $5760$ numbers. Right?

Comment: Correct; and as noted in my answer, they can be paired up so that each pair adds to $25200$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of prime factors of $N$ is small, you can find the desired sum by continually correcting for higher and higher numbers of shared prime factors.

You start by adding all the numbers less than $N$, as shown below. Let $n$ be the number of prime factors shared between $N$ and an arbitrary number less than $N$.

$$\begin{matrix}
n&0&1&2&3&4 \\
{\rm  Times\  counted:}&1&1&1&1&1
\end{matrix}$$

By subtracting numbers for each shared prime factor, we get the following:

$$\begin{matrix}
n&0&1&2&3&4 \\
{\rm  Times\  counted:}&1&0&-1&-2&-3
\end{matrix}$$

As you noted, you seem to be stuck on the negative values for $n\geq2$. We can simply correct for these by adding back values that share a pair of prime factors (ie. $6,10,15$). For each triple, there are 3 unique pairs, and for each quadruple, there are 6 pairs, so we get the following:

$$\begin{matrix}
n&0&1&2&3&4 \\
{\rm  Times\  counted:}&1&0&0&1&3
\end{matrix}$$

Now we can subtract the values that are divisible by a triple of prime factors (ie. $30,42$). There are 4 unique triples in the quadruple, so:

$$\begin{matrix}
n&0&1&2&3&4 \\
{\rm  Times\  counted:}&1&0&0&0&-1
\end{matrix}$$

Finally, we can add back the quadruple shared prime factors (divisible by $210$) to get the following:

$$\begin{matrix}
n&0&1&2&3&4 \\
{\rm  Times\  counted:}&1&0&0&0&0
\end{matrix}$$

And this is your desired result. In general, you can find the sum of the coprime numbers by subtracting for odd numbers of prime factors, and adding back for even numbers of prime factors.